# Duplication in maven: are profiles additive to project, or do they replace declared items?

Tags: maven

Provided you have the following defined in your `POM.xml`:

```
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>plugin-X</artifactId>
        <!-- plugin config -->
      </plugin>
    <plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>foo</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>plugin-X</artifactId>
            <!-- plugin config -->
          </plugin>
        <plugins>
      </build>
    <profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

If the plugin config for `plugin-X` is exactly the same for profile `foo` as it is for a build without a selected profile, do you have to redeclare the plugin at all on the profile level? If so, do you also have to redeclare all config settings for it?

If you declared `plugin-Y` in `project.profile.build.plugins` instead of `plugin-X` (but left it declared on the `project` level), which plugins would be run when you run `mvn -P foo`? Only `plugin-Y`, or also `plugin-X`?

More generally speaking, **are profiles additive to what is declared on the `project` level**, or do they override it? (If they are additive, how do you "remove" entities that were declared on a `project` level when you run a build `profile` and don't want them for that specific `profile`?)

I know profile configuration gets [inherited](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) from **parent pom files** ("from either the build/plugins or pluginManagement sections of the parent") with options "merge", "append", and "override". I think what I really want to know is: how does maven behave when the same/similar information is defined on the `project` and `profile` levels in **the same pom file**...

Comment: The POM's XSD only speaks of "[modification](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-model/maven.html#class_profile)", but judging from [Sonatype's maven reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-maven-profiles.html#profiles-sect-overriding-pom), it's overriding per section (e.g. `plugin`): "In this example, we’re overriding the behavior of the Compiler plugin and we have to override the plugin configuration which is normally enclosed in a `build` and a `plugins` element." If that holds true, I'd have to re-declare project-X's config, but both X and Y would run.

Comment: Coming to think of it, I could probably use [`pluginManagement`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) to stop repeating myself. However, I'm not sure if "it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one" includes those build definitions in profiles in the same POM. However " if we apply [these specifications] under the pluginManagement element, then this POM and _all inheriting POMs_ [are affected]"

Comment: First question I have about your setup is. Why do you need profiles for plugin configurations? Can you give a concrete example where you need that?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I'm trying to take a multi-module legacy project apart... ;-)

Comment: So, apparently, overriding might only affect parts of a `plugin` section. For example, you can [configure the `war` plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html#Invocation_of_war:inplace_goal) without having to redefine its `executions` section...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but another piece of the puzzle - in addition to [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328336/duplication-in-maven-are-profiles-additive-to-project-or-do-they-replace-decla#comment79625002_46328336) [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328336/duplication-in-maven-are-profiles-additive-to-project-or-do-they-replace-decla#comment79625492_46328336) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328336/duplication-in-maven-are-profiles-additive-to-project-or-do-they-replace-decla#comment79644474_46328336), and maven's [Guide to Configuring Plug-ins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_inherited_Tag_In_Build_Plugins).

Given the following `pom.xml` file:

```
</profiles>
    <properties>
        <foo>main</foo>
        <bar>main</bar>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>${foo}</echo>
                                <echo>${bar}</echo>
                                <echo>${baz}</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>p</id>
            <properties>
                <bar>prof</bar>
                <baz>prof</baz>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn validate`, I get the following output:

```
 [echo] main
 [echo] main
 [echo] ${baz}
```

Running `mvn validate -P p` however yields:

```
 [echo] main
 [echo] prof
 [echo] prof
```

That means that `properties` at least are **merged**, appending new items and replacing those that are redefined.

Also, if I add another plugin to the profile (such as `surefire`), it will execute when running the profile with `mvn <phase> -P p`, so the profile inherits `antrun` and adds `surefire`. Plugin re-definitions however replace the original; adding

```
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>Tada!</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

only prints `Tada!`, but no longer the original `antrun` output (even when changing the new addition's phase to `initialize`. Adding `<inherited>true</inherited>` to any of the two plugin definitions doesn't make a difference. The behaviour might be plugin-specific, though.